# Angularjs: TypeError: Cannot read property _____ of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am creating a simple app to teach myself Angular, and I have the app broken into a main app.js as well as a services.js and a controllers.js.

From the services.js file, I am trying to grab data from JSON and pass it to my controller.js, and then simply spit out one of the values from the JSON into a console.log.

The weird thing is that putting in the entire data object from my service into the console spits out the entire object (sorry for the messed up formatting from the Chrome developer tools, hopefully this just gives an idea)...

`console.log(questions);` returns in the console:

`Objectconfig: Objectdata: Array[4]0: Objectanswers: Array[4]correctAnswer: "question_1_answers_1"question: "What did Coltrane play?"__proto__: Object1: Objectanswers: Array[4]correctAnswer: "question_2_answers_2"question: "What did Miles play?"__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }constructor: function Object() { [native code] }hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }toString: function toString() { [native code] }valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }2: Objectanswers: Array[4]correctAnswer: "question_3_answers_4"question: "What did Monk play?"__proto__: Object3: Objectanswers: Array[4]correctAnswer: "question_4_answers_3"question: "What did Ray Brown play?"__proto__: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]headers: function (name) {arguments: (...)get arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }set arguments: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }caller: (...)get caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }set caller: function ThrowTypeError() { [native code] }length: 1name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: function Empty() {}<function scope>status: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }constructor: function Object() { [native code] }hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }toString: function toString() { [native code] }valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }`

However, attempting to access an individual value, like:

`console.log(questions[0].correctAnswer);`

...gives me the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'correctAnswer' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://local.testingspace.com/js/global.js:49:33)
    at invoke (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:15265:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:15276:23)
    at $get (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:18580:28)
    at link (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:34222:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:18010:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:17404:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:17300:30)
    at $get.boundTranscludeFn (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:17424:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://local.testingspace.com/js/lib.js:18031:18) <ng-view class="ng-scope">`

Taking a look at the code below, does anyone know why I might be having this issue?

Thanks!

-Doron

**Here is the code in question:**

**app.js**

```
(function() {

    var JazzQuiz = angular.module('JazzQuiz', ['JazzQuiz.services', 'JazzQuiz.controllers', 'ngRoute']);

    JazzQuiz.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/quiz.html',
            controller: 'QuizCtrl',
            resolve: {
                questions: function (quizFactory) {
                    return quizFactory.getQuestions();
                },
                responses: function (quizFactory) {
                    return quizFactory.getResponses();

                }
            }
        })
        .when('/score', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/score.html',
            controller: 'ScoreCtrl',
            resolve: {
                responses: function(quizFactory) {
                    return quizFactory.getResponses();
                }
            }
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    }]);

})();
```

**services.js**

```
var services = angular.module('JazzQuiz.services' ,[]);

services.factory('quizFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var resp;
    resp = {
        getQuestions: function (){
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '../json/questions.json'
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
            return promise;

        },
        getResponses: function (){
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '../json/submissionResponses.json'
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                return data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };

    return resp;
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var ctrl = angular.module('JazzQuiz.controllers', []);

// controller that handles the display of questions and handling of answers
ctrl.controller('QuizCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, $timeout, questions, responses){

    $scope.quizContent = questions;
    $scope.quizResponses = responses;

    //this spits out the entire object in the console
    console.log(questions);

    //this gives me an error
    console.log(questions[0].correctAnswer);

    // more to come...
});
```

**questions.json**

```
[
        {
            "question": "What did Coltrane play?",
            "answers": [
                "saxophone",
                "trumpet",
                "guitar",
                "french horn"
            ],
            "correctAnswer": "question_1_answers_1"
        },
        {
            "question": "What did Miles play?",
            "answers": [
                "drums",
                "trumpet",
                "guitar",
                "french horn"
            ],
            "correctAnswer": "question_2_answers_2"
        },  
        {
            "question": "What did Monk play?",
            "answers": [
                "trombone",
                "tabla",
                "drums",
                "piano"
            ],
            "correctAnswer": "question_3_answers_4"
        },
        {
            "question": "What did Ray Brown play?",
            "answers": [
                "saxophone",
                "drums",
                "bass",
                "guitar"
            ],
            "correctAnswer": "question_4_answers_3"
        }                
]
```

Comment: Can you log the structure of the whole object logged?

Comment: So, if `questions[0].correctedAnswer` throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'correctAnswer' of undefined`, that means `questions[0].correctedAnswer` is `undefined`. The array is empty.

Comment: would be great if you could create a fiddle out for this. Also could you share console.log(questions);

Comment: The problem is that `console.log(questions[0].correctAnswer);` is returning before your `getQuestions`'s success handler was run...

Comment: OK, I just added the output from the whole object. As for putting all of this into a Fiddle or Plunkr, I'm having a hard time getting that to work with all of the files and dependencies, trying to combine stuff and will post a link to that as soon as it's done, but of course, any insights in the meantime would be cool. 

Cerbrus - is it possible that  `console.log(questions[0].correctAnswer)` is is returning before my getQuestions's success handler was run, even though I'm successfully getting the entire object when I do `console.log(questions)`?

Comment: Please log the console value of questions, if questions is undefined, there is nothing being returned to the controller (questions becomes a local variable of the function, and due that it doesn´t receive value, becomes undefined). questions may not be an array, that will also explain the issue.

Comment: Note the console: `Objectconfig: Objectdata: Array[4]` This means `questions` contains an `ObjectConfig` property that contains an object that contains a property named `Objectdata` which contains an array. In other words, `questions.Objectconfig.Objectdata[0].correctAnswer`

Comment: @Guillermo, `console.log(questions)` does indeed log out the object (see my big blob out output at the beginning of this question). It's just that trying to get an individual piece of data, like doing `console.log(data[0].correctAnswer)`, doesn't work. That DOES, however, work in the success handler of my services.js file. So I think that Cerbrus was on to something with his comment, I just don't know how fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your log output, I think your problem is that values returned from within a `success` handler of a `$http` request aren't returned in the promise chain, so your `success` handler isn't actually doing anything, and the promise value you are receiving in your controller is the entire `$http` response instead of just the resulting data. Try changing your service like so:

```
    getQuestions: function (){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../json/questions.json'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    },
    getResponses: function (){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../json/submissionResponses.json'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
```

and see if that makes the difference.

In the spirit of learning, observe that your error message is, in fact:

```
Cannot read property 'correctAnswer' of undefined
```

Note, that the expression you are evaluating is

```
questions[0].correctAnswer
```

Which means that `questions` is not the part that's undefined -- it's `questions[0]`, so either questions is:

- an empty array (because having even a single defined element would mean that the index 0 would be populated -- disregarding some quirky corner cases)
- an array that contains an undefined value as its first element (possible, but not likely in this case)
- not an array at all

Armed with that and the knowledge that `questions` does have a defined value you can figure out the rest: your `questions` object has properties like "data", "headers" and "status", which indicate that it is the `$http` response object.